# Framebuffer not detecting image

Tags: frame-buffer

The command,

```
fb-test -f 0
```

generates and displays a test pattern on the screen.

But, the command,

```
cp /home/root/test.jpg /dev/fb0
```

copies test image into dev/fb0 file but fails to display anything on the screen?

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Copying the bytes of a JPEG file to the framebuffer device doesn't display the image represented by the JPEG file. The file needs to be decoded by an application that understands the JPEG format, to get the actual image. Your system is working normally. You can use a command like `display` to decode the file and draw the image to the screen.

Comment: In the embedded OS I am building, the command 'display' is not recognized.

Comment: Well, you need to use some program that is available in your embedded Linux distribution, or add one. I can't help you with that part.